# C++ How to write generic comparator function for int, double, string etc using templates

Tags: c++, templates, generics

Hi I am trying to write a generic isLess compare function for int, double, null terminated character array etc. Below is my code for same, please help me understand how could we use this function for null terminated strings too.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
bool isLess(T &x, T &y)
{
    return x < y;
}

int main()
{
    int a(10), b(20);
    double c(2.0), d(3.0);
    cout<<isLess<int>(a,b)<<endl;
    cout<<isLess<double>(c,d)<<endl;
    //For above types, generic comparator works fine

    //but if we have to compare character represented string, how can we do this in our comparator
    //assume charaters strings are compared the same way as strcmp.


    //char *e = "str1";
    //char *f = "str2";
    //cout<<isLess<char*>(e,f)<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a template specialization for `const char*` based on the `strcmp()` function?

Comment: What does it mean for a string to be 'less than' another string? How can you generalize this to arbitrary types? You need specialications.

Comment: Add some const correctness to your code.

Comment: And the standard `std::less` is not good enough for you?

Comment: @RustyX: Of course, `std::less` doesn't specialize on `char*` either.

Comment: I mean only the name. If you specialize,  why not choose `std:less` to specialize,

Comment: @kapil you can override your isLess function providing a specific template type of char*

Comment: @CharlesAddis : tnx for letting me know a way to handle this, but I wished to know if we could, somehow bundle this functionality inside the isLess function. Kindly note that this is just a general example to understand if there could be situations where we have no way other than writing a specific template for a type (in this case char*).

Comment: @RustyX : Thank you for the suggestion :). But this is more of a conceptual question where I wish to know if there might be scenarios where we have no choice other than to write specific template for a type (char* in this case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::less` is pretty much the standard for that.

If you want, you can roll your own function that does the same except for `char*`. A solution would be to add a selector that either use your own comparator, and fallback to the standard if you don't provide one for a particular type:

```
struct my_string_compare {
    bool operator()(const char* a, const char* b) const {
        // do whatever you want here.
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct select_less {
    using type = std::less<T>;
};

template<>
struct select_less<char*> {
    using type = my_string_compare;
};

template<typename T>
using my_less = typename select_less<T>::type;
```

Then, you can use your function like that:

```
my_less<char*> char_less;

if (char_less("string1", "string2")) {
    // ...
}

my_less<int> int_less;

// Same as std::less<int>
if (int_less(7, 9)) {
    // ...
}
```

What's great is that if you need more overloads, you just add another specialization.

Another advantage is that you don't override any standard behavior. You either use your own struct, or the standard.

For an explanation of what the `using` does, see [typedef](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typedef) and [Using-declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration)

Comment: If you found an answer useful, don't forget to upvote it.

Comment: tnx for your response. Could you kindly let me now what 
using keyword does in the code 

struct select_less {
    using type = std::less<T>;
};

I'm pretty new to c++. I have seen usage for using namespace std;
but not able to understand semantics of using here.
tnx :)

Comment: may be reference could be helpful :)

Comment: getting [Error] expected nested-name-specifier before 'type' :/

template<typename T>
struct select_less {
    using type = std::less<T>;     //this line gives the above error 
};

Comment: The code seems completely fine. Ensure you got c++11 enabled.

Comment: I've updated my answer. I added references to explain what a using (or typedef) means.

Answer (score 1):

You can use comparators from the standard library (ie `std::less`).

That said, why not use generic lambdas if you want to define them for yourself?

```
auto isLess = [](auto &x, auto &y) {
    return x<y;
};

auto isLessStr = [](auto *x, auto *y) {
    // ... Use whatever you want here
};
```

Use them then as `isLess(a,b)` and `isLessChar(e, f)`.